# Setup a cronjob to run a php file and to change my sql database

Tags: php, sql

I have this database https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZvbM3wVgbMATrEVXGhrre/2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buy` (
  `paymentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `blogin` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mb` double(20,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `gb` double(20,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `created` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `expiry` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`paymentID`)
);

INSERT INTO `buy` (`paymentID`, `userID`, `blogin`, `mb`, `gb`, `created`, `expiry`, `status`) VALUES
    (1, '1', 'user1', 2.00000000, 0.00000000, '15-10-2018  18:24', '24-03-2019  15:43', 'ACTIVE'),
    (2, '2', 'user2', 0.00000000, 2.00000000, '15-10-2018  18:26', '22-03-2019  18:23', 'ACTIVE'),
    (3, '3', 'user3', 5.00000000, 0.00000000, '15-10-2018  19:23', '28-03-2019  10:18', 'ACTIVE'),
    (4, '4', 'user4', 2.00000000, 0.00000000, '15-10-2018  20:04', '15-04-2019  00:00', 'ACTIVE'),
    (5, '5', 'user5', 0.00000000, 5.00000000, '15-10-2018  20:16', '29-03-2019  15:43', 'ACTIVE'),
    (6, '1', 'user1', 4.00000000, 0.00000000, '15-10-2018  18:24', '24-04-2019  15:45', 'ACTIVE'),
    (7, '2', 'user2', 0.00000000, 2.00000000, '15-10-2018  18:26', '25-03-2019  23:43', 'ACTIVE');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `glogin` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `web1` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `server1` (`id`, `glogin`, `web1`) VALUES
    (1, 'user1', '6.00000000'),
    (2, 'user2', '0.00000000'),
    (3, 'user3', '5'),
    (4, 'user4', '2.00000000'),
    (5, 'user5', '0');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vlogin` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `web2` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `server2` (`id`, `vlogin`, `web2`) VALUES
    (1, 'user1', '0.00000000'),
    (2, 'user2', '4'),
    (3, 'user3', '0.00000000'),
    (4, 'user4', '0.00000000'),
    (5, 'user5', '5.00000000');
```

I need a PHP script to set up a cronjob that will update the database.

So, this is the input:

Buy:

[image: Buy]

Server1:

[image: Server1]

Server2:

[image: Server2]

And I want it to become like this after I run the PHP script:

buy2:

[image: buy2]

server1:

[image: server1 after]

server2:

[image: server2 after]

My script below doesn't do the job, because the row `expiry` in the table is `varchar` and it modifies also other rows marked with red:

[image: Result Image]

This is changing in `server1` and `server2` even if status is EXPIRED. How I stop this from happening? What is wrong in the code?

The cron PHP I am trying with:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","xxx","webpanel");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// Perform queries 
$hrefdate = date("d-m-Y H:i");  
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM buy");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    if (($row['status']= "ACTIVE") and ($hrefdate>=date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($row['expiry'])))){
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE buy SET status = 'EXPIRED' where paymentID='".$row['paymentID']."' ");
        //$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM server1"); //do not see point from this 
        //$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);

        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE server1 SET web1 =  web1 - '".$row['mb']."' where id='".$row['userID']."' ");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE server2 SET web2 =  web2 - '".$row['gb']."' where id='".$row['userID']."' ");
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you code need to look something like this:

To update only active one you need to look only on active ones with `status='ACTIVE'` inside `buy` update witch will not act on EXPIRED

**EDIT:** As your date is in `varchar` PHP could not handle that. `str_to_date()` helps to convert string to date.

```
$hrefdate = date("d-m-Y H:i");  


$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM buy WHERE str_to_date(expiry, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') <= str_to_date('".$hrefdate."', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i')");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        if($row['status']=='ACTIVE'){
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE buy SET status = 'EXPIRED' where paymentID='".$row['paymentID']."' AND status='ACTIVE'");

            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE server1 SET   web1 =  web1 - '".$row['mb']."' where id='".$row['userID']."' ");
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE server2 SET   web2 =  web2 - '".$row['gb']."' where id='".$row['userID']."' ");
        }

}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Also to save space and query time you can do:

```
$hrefdate = date("d-m-Y H:i");  
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM buy WHERE str_to_date(expiry, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') <= str_to_date('".$hrefdate."', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') AND status='ACTIVE'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE buy SET status = 'EXPIRED' where paymentID='".$row['paymentID']."' AND status='ACTIVE'");

            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE server1 SET   web1 =  web1 - '".$row['mb']."' where id='".$row['userID']."' ");
            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE server2 SET   web2 =  web2 - '".$row['gb']."' where id='".$row['userID']."' ");

}
mysqli_close($con);
```

I m not saying it works but this is 99% as it should be looking.

Comment: is working ... but now the only problem is making EXPIERD for date > $hrefdate . For ex. is making for expiry = 15-04-2019  06:04  and this is > than  $hrefdate and this shoud remain ACTIVE

Comment: paymentID  userID  blogin  mb  gb  created  expiry  status
3  3  user3  5.00000000  0.00000000  15-10-2018  19:23  28-03-2019  10:18  ACTIVE
4  4  user4  2.00000000  0.00000000  15-10-2018  20:04  15-04-2019  06:04  EXPIRED
5  5  user5  0.00000000  5.00000000  15-10-2018  20:16  25-03-2019  17:33  EXPIRED
6  1  user1  4.00000000  0.00000000  15-10-2018  18:24  15-04-2019  06:04  EXPIRED

Comment: for ex:  in row expiry  have 15-04-2019  06:04         and shoud remain status= ACTIVE   but is changing to EXPIRED and run the script for this in other tables server1 and server2

Comment: No. I think the problem is here  if ($hrefdate>=date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($row['expiry'])))  when try to compare the date .

Comment: I show the problem in this Image with red in table buy https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RaeI.png

Comment: I think there are no problems with `if ($hrefdate>=date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($row['expiry']))){`  . .. Did you updated back status to start position before you tested it again? I think you keep testing with the same data without roollback. Update your data to state where it is correct and only then try cron again

Comment: 15-10-2018  20:04  15-04-2019  00:00  EXPIRED

Comment: user1  4.00000000  0.00000000  15-10-2018  18:24  24-04-2019  15:45  EXPIRED               and 24-04-2019  15:45 is  > than today

Comment: :))) yep  tnxxxxxx @Ingus

Comment: and @trincot  tnx